# Error with my contact form, NoMethodError in Contacts#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get this error when I try the create a new email. What's happening?

```
NoMethodError in Contacts#new

blog/app/views/contacts/new.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `contacts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fab694b2320>:0x007fab6bdde2a8>
Did you mean?  controller_path
```

Here is my code:

```
<div class="skinny_wrapper wrapper_padding">
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, required: true %>
```

[Here is my project](https://github.com/EQuimper/MyBlog)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title because specifying what technology is not necessary, that is what tags are for. I also fixed the grammar and casing of the words. Another thing I did was format the error so it easier to read. Lastly, I formatted the link to your repository. Hope you get your answer!

Comment: Thank you sorry for the grammar I'm not native english.

Answer (score 0):

OK, quickly looked at your routes.rb,

```
resources :contacts, only: [:new, :created]
```

is not well formed it should be:

```
resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
```

That's probably it. To see what's happening you can run **rake routes** and you'll see the list of your routes. Then you can fix the route file to have appropriate route path